# Shaft Size design / replacement

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, applied-mechanics

does anyone have any idea what standard shaft size / adapter this is?
the motor is NEMA 56C and the socket size it self is 27.8 mm in diameter and 32 overall with the key.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to double-check those (very cute but not very engineering-related) imgur links!

Comment: does it show correctly?

Comment: It is difficult to see from the images - does the motor shaft have a removable sleeve that forms the key, or is the key part permanently attached to the shaft?  FWIW I have never seen a rounded shaft key on standard parts, so this is most likely a manufacturer's specific fitment.  Normally shaft keys are made from square section key stock that slips into a groove in the shaft and in the pulley and are standard sizes to allow exchange of components.

Comment: What is the driven item? looks like a gearbox. What mfg?

Answer (score 1):

From Baldor motor chart, 5/8" diameter shaft with 3/16" keyway.

Comment: Add a link/citation, and this would be a good answer

Comment: Yes, the shaft geometry is standard for the 56C specification, although there can be some variation in the location of the shaft and keyway wrt the standard mounting geometry, which is annoying. I go back to the machine mfg for replacement 56C motors and pay the extra few bucks to make sure I get the right thing.

Comment: However, I think the question is about the adapter gadget.